# How do you clip the output of DrawFocusRect()?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a child window that has the `CS_PARENTDC` class style. This child window has a few items and I need to draw a focus rect on the item the user clicks on. If the item lies outside of the child client area, the focus rect is drawn outside of the client area. If the focus rect lies outside of the child client area I could make it smaller, but then it would not have a standard look. What's the best way to clip the output of `DrawFocusRect()`?

Comment: Clip the HDC that is passed to `DrawFocusRect()`. See the various [clipping functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183436.aspx) for working with HDC clipping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `IntersectClipRect()` did the job